# Does installing R and Python with Anaconda affect current installations?

Tags: python, r, anaconda, linux-mint

I am running Linux Mint 18.1 and have installed R through the CRAN repo. I use it mostly with R-Studio and emacs. I am just getting started with python programming and found the recommendation to use Anaconda. I also learned that Anaconda can set up different Environments and install different Versions of both R and Python. My question is if I can safely add environments install R and Python despite my current installations and use them with Jupyter Notebook? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: anaconda will not delete or write into any of your previous installations. It uses fully capsulated environments. Depending on your PATH settings it will however shadow previously installed python and R versions, giving its own installations precedence. You can control that once you understand how conda environments work exactly

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the reply!